# Generic Controller class?

Tags: apex, controller

I have a custom Visualforce extension which accesses information stored in custom settings and exposes it as variables which can be referenced from Visualforce.  I'd like to be able to use this extension from a variety of pages, including those with standard controllers and custom controllers. In other words, I want to be able to do all of the following:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="SettingsExtension">
<apex:page controller="CustomController1" extensions="SettingsExtension">
<apex:page controller="CustomController2" extensions="SettingsExtension">
```

To do this, I've had to write the following constructors:

```
public SettingsExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    // code goes here
}

public SettingsExtension(CustomController1 controller) {
    // code goes here
}

public SettingsExtension(CustomController2 controller) {
    // code goes here
}

/* Etc. - each custom controller I use needs its own constructor */
```

**Is there a generic Controller class or Interface I can use in the constructor to avoid this Constructor proliferation?  I imagine it would look something like:**

```
public CustomExtension(ApexPages.BaseController controller) {
    // code goes here
}
```

Comment: what is it you're trying to accomplish in this constructor logic? Logic that needs to apply to all the visualforce pages? Couldn't you just put this extension in every extensions argument in each page `<apex:page extensions"">`

Comment: I usually put the utility methods in their own (often static) class and have each controller call them as it needs to.

Comment: @PJC, That's precisely what I'm trying to do.  The problem is I need to support all of the following: `<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="SettingsExtension">`, `<apex:page controller="CustomController1" extensions="SettingsExtension">`, and `<apex:page controller="CustomController2" extensions="SettingsExtension">`

Comment: As @BobBuzzard mentioned, I would try to refactor your code to utility methods so you write the code once there and invoke it individually in the different constructors.

Comment: @MichaelWelburn what about standard controllers?

Comment: If you write an extension class you should be able to override the standard controller constructor and call super() in it prior to executing your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move the utility code into a parent class and use the "extends" functionality to allow each controller to inherit the utilities:

```
public with sharing virtual class MyBaseClass {
    public Boolean checkIt(){
        return true;
    }
}

public with sharing virtual class MySecondClass extends MyBaseClass{
    Boolean isItTrue = checkIt();
}
```